# grouping columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

hello i am working with a dataset in .csv with python and am having errors grouping the columns. the code i'm working with is:

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.read_excel('filepath')
df['Items'].str.split(',', expand=True)
df=df.groupby(['Items0', 'Items1','Items2', 'Items3', 'Items4', 'Items5' ]).size()
print(df)
```

when i run the print(df) i get values such as Items0-1, Items1-1, Items2-1 and so on

this is the sample data i am working with and how i am trying to organize it is below.

can someone direct me to how to solve this?

sample data:

| Name | Date | Items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| johnny smith | 09/1/2021 | bread, oranges, peanut butter, apples, celery, peanuts |
| granny smith | 08/31/2021 | oranges, peanut butter, apples, bread |
| jane doe | 09/01/2021 | oranges, apples, celery, peanut butter |
| jack frost | 08/01/2021 | bread, oranges, apples |
| cinderella | 08/16/2021 | apples, peanuts, bread |

what i am attempting to achieve:

| Name | Date | Items0 | Items1 | Items2 | Items3 | Items4 | Items5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| johnny smith | 09/1/2021 | bread | oranges | peanut butter | apples | celery | peanuts |
| granny smith | 08/31/2021 | bread | oranges | peanut butter | apples |  |  |
| jane doe | 09/01/2021 |  | oranges | peanut butter | apples |  |  |
| jack frost | 08/01/2021 | bread | oranges |  | apples |  |  |
| cinderella | 08/16/2021 | bread |  |  | apples |  | peanuts |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to derive categorical values from the string in `Items` then reformat the DataFrame and `join` back together:

```
x = df.pop('Items').str.get_dummies(', ')
df = df.join(
    x.mul(x.columns).set_axis(
        range(len(x.columns)), axis=1
    ).add_prefix('Item')
)
```

```
           Name        Date   Item0  Item1   Item2    Item3          Item4    Item5
0  johnny smith   09/1/2021  apples  bread  celery  oranges  peanut butter  peanuts
1  granny smith  08/31/2021  apples  bread          oranges  peanut butter         
2      jane doe  09/01/2021  apples         celery  oranges  peanut butter         
3    jack frost  08/01/2021  apples  bread          oranges                        
4    cinderella  08/16/2021  apples  bread                                  peanuts
```

---

Explanations: use [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) to convert the `Item` column to categorical values:

```
x = df.pop('Items').str.get_dummies(', ')
```

```
   apples  bread  celery  oranges  peanut butter  peanuts
0       1      1       1        1              1        1
1       1      1       0        1              1        0
2       1      0       1        1              1        0
3       1      1       0        1              0        0
4       1      1       0        0              0        1
```

This can be converted into the desired format by [`mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) by the column names (replacing the 1 values with the column name), [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) to enumerate columns (0-number of items) and [`add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) of 'Item' to the newly numbered columns:

```
x.mul(x.columns).set_axis(
    range(len(x.columns)), axis=1
).add_prefix('Item')
```

`x`:

```
    Item0  Item1   Item2    Item3          Item4    Item5
0  apples  bread  celery  oranges  peanut butter  peanuts
1  apples  bread          oranges  peanut butter         
2  apples         celery  oranges  peanut butter         
3  apples  bread          oranges                        
4  apples  bread                                  peanuts
```

Then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back to the remaining columns in `df` .